# Pass variable relative to the selector to multiple jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, events, mouseevent

I'm looking for a way to pass a variable that is relative to the element to both mouseenter and mouseleave events. For example, if I had:

```
jQuery('.element').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var $child = jQuery(this).find('.child');
        $child.fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var $child = jQuery(this).find('.child');
        $child.fadeOut();
    }    
});
```

Is there a way to avoid defining the $child variable twice? I was able to figure this out using .hover(), however I am now unable to use that as I am calling it on dynamically generated elements, for which .hover() will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way to delegate both events:

```
jQuery(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".element", function(e){
    jQuery(this).find('.child').fadeToggle();
    // you can check for e.type for more complex logic    
});
```

The syntax to delegate with different handlers is:

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //...
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //...
    }    
}, ".element");
```

Comment: In trying to simplify my example I may have misled you. I'm not simply fading in and out, but rather changing a CSS value on the .child element. Therefore I do need to define the functions separately for the two events.

Comment: Like i just posted in code comment `you can check for e.type for more complex logic`

Comment: excellent and simple using your first example combined and `if ( e.type == "mouseenter" ) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like that:

```
jQuery('.element').on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        var ele = e.currentTarget;
        ele.fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        var ele= e.currentTarget;
        ele.fadeOut();
    }    
});
```

Comment: I need to find a child of .element to use as variable

Comment: @johnnyd23 You'd have better to post relevant example of what you are looking for instead of unrelevant one then. Why would you need to use a variable for `.child`? What about posting a jsFiddle?

Comment: My question asked "Is there a way to avoid defining the $child variable twice?"

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the same function in both events, something like:

```
jQuery('.element').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        handleFade("enter", jQuery(this));
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        handleFade("leave", jQuery(this));
    }    
});

function handleFade(state, $elem){
    var $child = $elem.find('.child');
    if(state=="enter"){
        $child.fadeIn();
    } else if(state=="leave"){
        $child.fadeOut();
    }
}
```